# Python 3.7 altinstall and installing PIP: PyCharm: unix system

Tags: linux, python-3.x, pycharm, ubuntu-16.04

I decided to I wanted to test the newest version of Python. I downloaded from source and performed an altinstall so python3.7 (full) in located in usr/local/lib and its executable is @ usr/local/bin. I thought an easy way to go about getting modules installed would be to select this executable as my Project Interpreter in PyCharm and use its package manager to install pip and whatnot. However, when I select 3.7 executable as the: Virtualenv Environment it will not allow me to hit 'ok'. Instead a warning at the bottom left of the window says:

```
Environment location directory is not empty
```

So I tried selecting the executable as the System Interpreter and it works to an extent. It allows me to hit ok but in the package manager window there is a yellow bar at the bottom that says:

```
Python packaging tools not found. Install packaging tools
```

So if I click the link it attempts an install (requires sudo) and then instead of installing, a warning box pops up:

```
Failed to install Python packaging tools:
ModuleNotFoundError: No moudle named'_ctypes'
```

So, how do I get PyCharm to use 3.7 s/t I can install modules for it?

Comment: Did you find a way to solve it?

Comment: Looks like you're missing the libffi-dev package. Install it first before building python (so install yum/apt-get/whatever install libffi-dev, then go to the pythondir and recompile (i.e. make altinstall)), then try again. 

Note that PyCharm depends on pip3.7 being installed, this should come with python3.7.